# Is there a tool to create MySQL database model from an existing MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, data-modeling

I am looking for a piece of software to allow me easily create the database mode for an existing MySQL database

Answer (score 2):

If you use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) with the --no-data option, you can extract the schema from the old database. There can be issues with views using this method, see [this article for a workaround.](http://mysqlhacker.com/kabir/dba/exporting-dumping-views-using-mysqldump.html)

You can copy a schema in this way with something like this:

```
mysqldump --opt --no-data olddatabase | mysql newdatabase
```

Answer (score 2):

You can dump the database schema to SQL using the mysqldump command.

```
mysqldump {databasename} --no-data=true -u {username} -p  > database_schema.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/ is still in Beta (depending on your Operating System), but can be a handy tool for exploring the schema of databases - there is a free version to.

Use mysqldump on your DB as the other answers state then import the resulting file into this program.

Answer (score 0):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is my go-to MySQL non-command line management program. Comes with most installations of MySQL on web servers and [WAMP, MAMP, and LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMP_packages) configurations. It's about 95% of what I need when dealing with developing DB apps on top of MySQL, and has easy export options to handle your request.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) for many years for creating/managing and migrating MySQL databases. It is free and can make copying structures or entire databases between different hosts a breeze.